# React Array of Objects useState from Fetch call assignment

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I don't know how to assign an array of objects into an `useState` variable.

Here is the code where data variable is retrieved as an array of objects. I would assign the data variable inside the `Fetch` call to assign the value into the `useState` variable called `tc1list`:

```
const [tc1list, setTC1List] = useState([]);  //tc1list variable remains empty after fetch call

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8089/api/tc/gettc1/0')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('data:', data);
        setTC1List(data);  // <<<<<======== How should be done here the assignment?
        console.log('tc1list:', tc1list);  <<<<=== Here tc1list is still empty....
      });
  }, []);
```

Data variable returns ok (here I list only the first array object returned from fetch call).

Data array variable has a structure like this:

```
[ {tc1id: 1,createdat: "2020-04-16,.... },{.....},{.....},.... ]
```

Example of data variable returned at index 0:

```
tc1id: 1

createdat: "2020-04-16T08:48:56.213+0000"

updatedat: "2020-04-16T08:48:56.213+0000"

tipoMan: "MMP"

dataReg: "2020-04-15T22:00:00.000+0000"

codSezArr: "000000"

handlerDest: ""

codSezPart: "015101"

handlerPort: "handler"

codGest: ""

codMag: ""

dataRegFine: "2020-04-24T22:00:00.000+0000"

dataMezzo: "2020-03-31T22:00:00.000+0000"

oraInizio: "1970-01-01T04:55:00.000+0000"

oraFine: "1970-01-01T17:21:00.000+0000"
```

...etc...

Assignment using the code below gives an empty tc1list array...

> `setTC1List(data)`

gives empty array!

tc1list: []

Comment: `console.log('tc1list:', tc1list);` will be empty because the `setTC1List` is asynchronous, so the latest value of `tc1list` will be available on the next render. Try to `console.log` it right before you `return` your `JSX`.

Comment: States are asynchronous component, you can't use their value after the call of setState. 
The change will be effective on you page, but not in this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State are asynchronous , so you can't see the change at that moment.

If you want to do more operation after the change of a set , you can use a specified useEffect :

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log('After setTC1LIST' ,tc1list);
// What you want to do 
}, [tc1list]); //notice this declaration of tc1list
// every state in this array will triger the call of the effect on change
```

This will triger everytime you use `setTC1List`